# remove extra objects from string or array while hitting api

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swifty-json

I wanna pass whole array to api which expects string. My `"education"` expects any string like `"education" : "ncert"` but I wanna pass multiple elements to it. So to pass multiple elements I created an array and passed whole array and got this result from the api response:

```
"education" : "[\"ncert\", \"hello\", \"bye\", \"cbse\", \"hmmm\"]"
```

but is there any way to pass contents in this format?:

```
"education" : "ncert, hello, bye, cbse, hmmm"
```

I saw a code which uses `replace(target: "[", replacement: "")` but is there any way I can do this in swift?

Comment: How do you create that output? The issue is there...

Comment: I just add contents to array one by one..like first ncert then case etc. and final array I print is ['ncert', "case", "hello"]..like normal but when I pass it to api..forkey: "education". it changes into that format

Comment: At some point, you can use `joined(separator:)` transforming your array of string, into a string. Then give it to your API...

Comment: it worked,"joined(separator: ", ")" worked perfectly. Thanks. Just in case if I want "education" : "ncert", "hello", "bye", "cbse", "hmmm"...every content inside " "..will it be possible?